# ForEach inside ScrollView doesn't take whole width

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to re-create UI of my current app using SwiftUI. And it is way more difficult than I initially though. 
I wanted to achieve card-like cells with some background behind them. I found that `List` doesn't support that, at least yet. `List` is so limited - it doesn't allow you to remove cell separator.

So I moved to `ForEach` inside `ScrollView`. I guess that isn't something which should be used in production for long tables but that should work for now. The problem I have is that `ForeEach` view doesn't take all the width `ScrollView` provides. I can set `.frame(...)` modifier but that will require hardcoding width which I definitely don't want to do.

Any ideas how to force `VStack` take full width of the ScrollView? I tried to use `ForeEach` without `VStack` and it has the same issue. It seems like `ScrollView` (parent view) "tells" its child view (VStack) that its frame is less that actual `ScrollView`'s frame. And based on that information child views build their layout and sizes.

Here is my current result:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
struct LandmarkList : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView() {
                VStack {
                    Spacer().frame(height: 160)
                    ForEach(landmarkData) { landmark in
                        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark).padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
                    }
                }.scaledToFill()
                .background(Color.pink)
            }
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))

        }
    }
}

struct LandmarkRow : View {
    var landmark: Landmark

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(landmark.name).font(.title)
                Text("Subtitle")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .color(.gray)
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("5 mi")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            }.frame(height: 80)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(16)
            .clipped()
            .shadow(radius: 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: you can add VStack to HStack with Spacer() at bottom and top it will take full screen. Don't know this will work with scroll view or not

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya if I add `HStack` with `VStack` and `Spacer` cells won't become full width.
At Building Custom Views talk Apple engineer explained how sizing works. From what I see here - `ScrollView` doesn't pass its size but rather, some `ScrollViewContent` size (it's not an actual name) which is smaller than `ScrollView` itself. Replacing `ScrollView` to another view fixes the problem but I loose scrolling functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible that the answer to this might just be wrapping your scrollView inside of a `GeometryReader`

Like done in the answer here -> [How do I stretch a View to its parent frame with SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56630578/how-do-i-stretch-a-view-to-its-parent-frame-with-swiftui/56630767#56630767)

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same issue, the only way I have found so far is to fix the `ScrollView` and the content view **width**, so that every subview you add inside the content view will be centered.

I created a simple wrapper that take the width as init parameter

```
struct CenteredList<Data: RandomAccessCollection, Content: View>: View where Data.Element: Identifiable {

    public private(set) var width: Length
    private var data: Data
    private var contentBuilder: (Data.Element.IdentifiedValue) -> Content

    init(
        width: Length = UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
        data: Data,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Data.Element.IdentifiedValue) -> Content)
    {
        self.width = width
        self.data = data
        self.contentBuilder = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(data) { item in
                    return self.contentBuilder(item)
                }.frame(width: width)
            }
            .frame(width: width)
        }
        .frame(width: width)
    }
}
```

By default it takes the screen width (`UIScreen.main.bounds.width`).

It works just like a `List` view:

```
var body: some View {
    TileList(data: 0...3) { index in
        HStack {
            Text("Hello world")
            Text("#\(index)")
         }
    }
}
```