# How do I stretch a View to its parent frame with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Below you see the image and the black square i want to stretch to the red borders.

I have tried the following

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 1) {
            Rectangle().frame(width:20).foregroundColor(.red).frame(width:20)
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                        Rectangle().frame(minWidth: 50, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 50)
                    }
                }.relativeWidth(1)
            }
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red).frame(width:20)
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View { ContentView() }
}
#endif
```

but result is this:

[image]

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://stackoverflow.com/q/56534772/1187415

Comment: it does seem to be a duplicate.. sorry. (..but this question was phrased so much simpler to demonstrate the problem?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ForEach inside ScrollView doesn't take whole width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534772/foreach-inside-scrollview-doesnt-take-whole-width)

Comment: @Rivera no. I have have already accepted the answer that works here. Also, on that question you linked to, the answer to that question is my answer which links to the answer here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader) and wrap your ScrollView into it and set content width to the geometry's width size. A `GeometryReader`:

> returns a flexible preferred size to its parent layout.

So your code would be something like below:

```
HStack(spacing: 1) {
     Rectangle().frame(width:20).foregroundColor(.red).frame(width:20)
     GeometryReader { geometry in
          ScrollView {
               VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                         Rectangle().frame(minWidth: 50, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 50)
                    }
                }.relativeWidth(1)
               .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
          }
     }
     Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red).frame(width:20)
}
```

Comment: Does this build on your end? Maybe if you paste the full code edit? If i past this in the sample i get build error at `HStack(spacing: 1)`

Comment: @iOSCalendarpatchthecode.com sorry, had an extra "}" :]

Comment: ok this works!! but why ヽ(ಠ_ಠ)ノ?   Is this a hack to fix a bug?

Comment: @iOSCalendarpatchthecode.com Updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Another (less) ugly hack to fix `ScrollView`s' width in SwiftUI:

```
ScrollView {
    // ...
    Divider().opacity(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Following will also give you the result you are looking for:

```swift
HStack(spacing: 1) {
    Rectangle().frame(width:20).foregroundColor(.red).frame(width:20)
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                Rectangle().frame(minHeight: 50)
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red).frame(width:20)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you use iOS 17+ you can use containerRelativeFrame:

```
struct ContentView: View {

let items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
                    .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical])
                    .background { Color.green }
            }
        }
    }
    .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
}
```

}