# ScrollView Not Taking Full Width When List Inside Is Empty

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created a list inside a scroll view that works fine when it has items, but I've noticed that when there are not items in the list that the scroll view is very narrow and it makes it hard to use the refreshabled. I have tried many solutions online such as using extra spacers, GeometryReady width, and other things but nothing seems to fix it.

Here is my view's code:

```swift
struct PostsView: View {
    
    private var userId: String
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: PostsViewModel
    @StateObject var loadingState: PostsLoadingState
    @State var isShowingDeleteConfirm: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(stops: [
                Gradient.Stop(color: Color("Cottage Green Tertiary"), location: 0.0),
                Gradient.Stop(color: Color("Cottage Green Tertiary"), location: 0.85),
                Gradient.Stop(color: Color("Cottage Dark Green"), location: 1.0)
            ], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                ForEach(Array(self.viewModel.posts.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, post in
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            if self.viewModel.canDeletePost(postIndex: index) {
                                Button {
                                    self.viewModel.latestPostIndexSelectedToDelete = index
                                    self.isShowingDeleteConfirm = true
                                } label : {
                                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                                        .foregroundStyle(Color("Cottage Dark Green"))
                                }
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            Text(getDateDescription(from: post.datePosted))
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                .padding(.bottom, 10)
                        }
                        Text(post.message)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.bottom, 10)
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                                .foregroundStyle(Color("Cottage Dark Green"))
                            Text(post.poster.name)
                            Spacer()
                            Button {
                                let impactMed = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
                                impactMed.impactOccurred()
                                if post.likers.contains(where: { $0 == self.userId }) {
                                    self.viewModel.removeLike(from: self.userId, for: index)
                                } else {
                                    self.viewModel.addLike(from: self.userId, for: index)
                                }
                            } label : {
                                if post.likers.contains(where: { $0 == self.userId }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsup.fill")
                                        .foregroundStyle(Color("Cottage Dark Green"))
                                } else {
                                    Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsup")
                                        .foregroundStyle(Color("Cottage Dark Green"))
                                }
                            }
                            Text(String(post.likers.count))
                        }
                    }
                    .padding([.top, .bottom, .leading, .trailing], 10)
                    .background(Color("Cottage Green"))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                .padding([.top, .bottom, .leading, .trailing], 10)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .frame(width: geo.size.width)
            .alert(isPresented: $isShowingDeleteConfirm) {
                Alert(
                    title: Text("Delete Post?"),
                    message: nil,
                    primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                        self.viewModel.deletePost()
                    },
                    secondaryButton: .cancel()
                )
            }
            .refreshable {
                print("Do your refresh work here")
                do {
                    try await viewModel.getPosts()
                } catch {
                    
                }
            }
            
            if self.loadingState.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            }   
        } 
    }
}
public init(viewModel: PostsViewModel, userId: String, loadingState: PostsLoadingState) {
        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
        self.userId = userId
        self._loadingState = StateObject(wrappedValue: loadingState)
    }
        
    func getDateDescription(from date: Date) -> String {
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        
        return formatter.string(from: date)
        
    }
    
}
```

Here is the Post model's code:

```
struct Post : Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var id: String
    var poster: Attendee
    var message: String
    var responses: [PostResponse]
    var likers: [String]
    var datePosted: Date
    
    init(id: String, poster: Attendee, message: String, responses: [PostResponse] = [], likers: [String] = [], datePosted: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.poster = poster
        self.message = message
        self.responses = responses
        self.likers = likers
        self.datePosted = datePosted
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Post, rhs: Post) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id && rhs.id == lhs.id
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        return hasher.combine(self.id)
    }
    
}
```

And finally here is the ViewModel's code:

```
@MainActor
class PostsViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    
    @Published var posts: [Post]
    private(set) var cottageId: String
    var latestPostIndexSelectedToDelete: Int?
    
    weak var delegate: PostsViewModelProtocol?
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    init(cottageId: String, posts: [Post]) {
        self.cottageId = cottageId
        self.posts = posts
    }
    
    //MARK: - Functions
    
    func getPosts() async throws {
        
        do {
            self.posts = try await PostsService.shared.getPosts(in: self.cottageId)
        } catch {
            self.posts = []
        }
        
    }
    
    func addLike(from attendeeId: String, for postIndex: Int) {
         
        var post: Post = self.posts[postIndex]
        post.likers.append(attendeeId)
        
        Task {
            try await PostsService.shared.likePost(cottageId: self.cottageId, postId: post.id, attendeeId: attendeeId)
        }
        
        self.posts[postIndex] = post
                
    }
    
    func removeLike(from attendeeId: String, for postIndex: Int) {
        
        var post: Post = self.posts[postIndex]
        post.likers.removeAll(where: { $0 == attendeeId })
        
        Task {
            try await PostsService.shared.removeListFromPost(cottageId: self.cottageId, postId: post.id, attendeeId: attendeeId)
        }
        
        self.posts[postIndex] = post
        
    }
    
    func canDeletePost(postIndex: Int) -> Bool {
        
        let postToCheck: Post = self.posts[postIndex]
        
        return postToCheck.poster.firebaseUserID == Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        
    }
    
    func deletePost() {
        
        guard
            let latestPostIndexSelectedToDelete
        else { return }
        
        if self.posts[latestPostIndexSelectedToDelete].poster.firebaseUserID != Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
            return
        }
        
        print("Deleting post with message: \(self.posts[latestPostIndexSelectedToDelete].message)")
        
        let postToDelete: Post = self.posts[latestPostIndexSelectedToDelete]
        
        Task {
            do {
                try await PostsService.shared.deletePost(postId: postToDelete.id, cottageId:self.cottageId)
                self.posts.remove(at: latestPostIndexSelectedToDelete)
            } catch {
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

//MARK: - Protocol Implementations

extension PostsViewModel : CreatePostProtocol {
    
    func postCreated() {
        
        Task {
            try await self.getPosts()
            if let delegate {
                delegate.postsLoaded()
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

protocol PostsViewModelProtocol : AnyObject {
    
    func postsLoaded()
    
}
```

Here is what it looks like when it is empty:
[image]

Any help is appreciated as I am fairly new to SwiftUI! Thanks!

Comment: have you tried this answer?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56630578/how-do-i-stretch-a-view-to-its-parent-frame-with-swiftui/56630767#56630767

Comment: Add `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` to the ScrollView to make it full width

Comment: I tried your example code, after removing unrelated actions from viewModel and also adding an empty array, it works fine. It seems like the issue comes from the parent view. `GeometryReader` does the right thing.

Comment: @Kushagra I had already tried this and unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Yes it is already in a geometry reader using it's width, this did not solve it

Comment: @son okay that is helpful to know, I will see if I can see why the parent view is causing this

Comment: It would be helpful to have the code for the view model and `Post` so that we can attempt to reproduce, or break this down to a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @DavidB. I have updated the post to include these, sorry!